# Computing $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z_n,G)$ by left-exactness

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

In chapter 2 of Rotman's *An introduction to homological algebra*, we are set the exercise to show,

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z_n, G) = \{g\in G : ng = 0\}$$

where $G$ is an abelian group, hinting to use the left-exactness of $\mathrm{Hom}$. As far as I understand, this means choosing a useful exact sequence,

$$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$

and using the induced sequence,

$$0\to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z_n,A) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z_n,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z_n,C).$$

Obviously either $A, B$ or $C$ I am guessing must be chosen as $G$, but I don't know how to proceed from here and which modules to choose for the computation.

Is my approach correct and if so how do I proceed? A hint is appreciated rather than a full answer.

Comment: You do not need to use exactness. Just write down the definition of a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $G$. It is determined by what it does to a generator $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_n$; what condition does that generator have to satisfy?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Its order must divide $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead $\mathrm{Hom}(-,G)$ instead. In particular, you have

$$0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \to 0.$$

Then
$$0 \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z,G) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z,G) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z,G)$$
is exact.

> Of course, this is really 
>    \begin{align}0 \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z,G) \to G \to G.\end{align}
> what are the maps?

Comment: The original map is $f : x \mapsto x \mod n$. Then $\hom (f,G) : \psi \mapsto \psi(1)$, where $\hom (f,G) : \hom(\mathbb Z_n,G) \to G$. Then $\hom(\mathbb Z_n,G) \cong \mathrm{im}\, f = \{\psi | \psi(n) = n\psi(1) = 0\} \cong \{g \in G | ng = 0\}$.